# Гистограмма нормального распределения excel

Tags: excel

Как в Эксель построить подобную гистограмму нормального распределения имея 100 значений от -2 до 2,5?
Я использовал функцию НОРМ.РАСП(A1;СРЗНАЧ(A$1:A$100);СТАНДОТКЛОНА(A$1:A$100);0)

когда я получил результат, я выделил все получившиеся значения, и выбрал Вставка->гистограмма..
У меня вышло непонятное какое-то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно непонятное?

Comment: на фото график - примерный результат к которому я должен придти, в середине 0 и распределение влево и вправо, в моем случае выходит непонятно что (

Comment: А где "непонятне какое-то"?

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/7e55fb42c1f26cf54a854d01ce9fdf90 Вот скриншот )

Comment: @vikttur возможно что неверно строю диаграмму

Comment: Похоже, что неверно ) Пример надо показывать, а не картинку.

Comment: @vikttur вот входные значения
0,5 0,45 0,45 0,45 0,45 0,5 0,8 1,4 1,75 1,75 2,5 1,7 1,2 1,2 1 1,5 1,2 1,5 1,8 2 1,5 1,5 1,8 2 1,5 1,8 2,2 2 1,5 1,5 1,2 1,4 1,4 0,85 0,65 1,7 0,75 0,95 1 0,7 0,7 0,65 0,7 0,8 0,65 0,7 0,6 0,75 0,7 0,69 0,69 0,7 0,75 0,8 0,95 0,8 0,7 0,73 0,69 0,7 0,65 0,65 0,73 0,73 0,76 0,7 0,65 0,65 0,8 1 1,2 1,6 2

Вот формула НОРМ.РАСП(A1;СРЗНАЧ(A$1:A$100);СТАНДОТКЛОНА(A$1:A$100);1)
Я выбираю значения получившиеся в формуле и строю гистограмму, но она далеко не похожа на "колокол"